# Customizing the default logout page of WordPress

Tags: customization, filters, hooks, login

What are the proper filter/hooks to modify the wp-login.php?action=logout confirmation page

[image]When you logout of your site using **yoursite.com/wp-login.php?action=logout** , You will go to a standard page WordPress logout page that has the following text:

> You are attempting to log out of "Your Site"
>
> Do you really want to log out?

I do not see any hooks/filters to modify it, I have checked from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url

What is the best way to edit this page?

Answer (score 2):

Its seems we don't have any hook to modify that page. But you can use alternative way and redirect user to a desire template and modify that template according to your needs.

```
 <?php wp_loginout( $redirect, $echo ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout
This might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can except to go to that logout page.
Only you need to change your logout link in your frontend.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url()?>">logout</a>
```

this code, make the logout without confirmation window.

But also if you really need a confirmation, you can create a "new page" named "confirmation" now, in your frontend the logout can point to "/confirmation" you put there your nice styles, and the link using "wp_logout_url()" or you can make a nice js/bootstrap confirmation event.

I hope that was helpfull.